# Can I query a table to generate variables in a live-template?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, live-templates

Would this be possible? I want to create Laravel models with some basic properties and for example, fill $fillable array with all database table fields names as default values.

Comment: No. As simple as that. Either write yourself custom tools (e.g. custom task for artisan -- possibly the best choice) ... or (if you prefer it to be run natively in IDE) write a plugin for IDE.

Comment: Well, I'll take a look on custom task for artisan as you suggested.IDE plugin sounds nice too as it would let my work mates to install so easy, thanks

Comment: Well .. Have you tried **Laravel IDE Helper**? I think it's a _must have_ if you are using Laravel and PhpStorm. Based on description it can generate PHPDoc for models -- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-for-models